# 1999 Accord Cranks but won't start after replacing ignition switch

Tags: honda, ignition, accord, cranks-wont-run

I have a 1999 Accord and the ignition switch recently stopped being able to be turned. It had been acting up and sometimes would turn and sometimes wouldn't, but whenever it turned, it started with no problems. I replaced the whole switch and now the key turns fine and it cranks but won't turn over.

Any idea what I screwed up?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the key is chipped.  New key is not matching up.  Could tell because the green key light is flashing on the dash when I try to start it.